# Is it considered bad form to ask OP to assign bounty if s/he has accepted your answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I don't want to come across as petty or ungrateful over what are essentially meaningless internet points, so I was just wondering what the rule or general concensus is in this situation. I feel I answered the question quite thoroughly and OP has accepted my answer.

Another answer did get more upvotes than mine though, so I assume this one would get the 50% auto bounty if OP doesn't actively do anything.

The question in question is [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48336/how-would-system-like-weregild-value-the-life-of-a-child).

Would a quick comment to OP asking what s/he is planning to do with the bounty (if anything) be acceptable, or should I just forget it?

EDIT:

Thinking about it, comments reminding OP to award bounty are about the same as comments reminding OP to accept an answer: Bad form, even if not specifically banned. I'll just leave it.

Answer (score 3):

The person who offered the bounty gets reminder email three days before the end, and again 24 hours before the end (I think), and again when the grace period starts.  (After the end of the seven days, the person still has 24 hours in which to award it.)  So the odds that the person will forget about the bounty are low.  So a reminder isn't necessary.

I *have* sometimes seen people comment asking what further information the bounty-giver is seeking, particularly when the bounty criteria are unclear in some way.  Such queries are on behalf of the whole community, in a way.  But, in general, my personal opinion is similar to what you added in your edit -- it feels a little like "plz accept my answer" and can rub people the wrong way.  While there's no rule against it, I would caution you against doing it.

Your understanding of the auto-award is a little off, by the way.  Here's what [the documentation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) says about it:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

Answers that were already present before the bounty started aren't eligible for the auto-award.  (All answers are eligible for a manual award.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the person who offered the bounty. It was my very first one and, I'd thought that accepting an answer was sufficient. Didn't see this question until just now, but I have already awarded the bounty because of the email reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any harm in asking.  But as you mention they are imaginary so I wouldn't worry about it too much either way.

Where bounty points go is totally up to the person offering and in the case of an accepted answer having less votes than another answer I am not 100% sure where they would go in an auto assigned situation.

My hunch would be it goes to the accepted answer but perhaps one of the other folks around here can verify that.

Comment: As far as I can tell in the faqs, autoawarded bounty goes to the answer with the most votes, so that would be the other one. I guess it doesn't really matter, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tad *odd* that the asker found one answer acceptable, but still felt the need to offer a bounty. Perhaps hindsight, and they really wished they waited for a new answer?

I, myself, am curious as to why she did that. However it doesn't break any rules (obviously) and I don't find it rude on her part.

Just look at it this way: If she doesn't reward you the bounty, you're no worse off (point wise) than if she never had offered it in the first place, and if what she wished she did was, indeed, hold off on accepting an answer and that's what she (hypothetically) *had* done you're actually in a better place point-wise.

TL;DR: I don't understand it (and am curious like you), you might still get the bounty, and if you don't get the bounty you're not worse for the wear.

Comment: Sorry, I might have worded my Q wrong. The answer with the most votes was posted first, then the OP offered the bounty, and then I posted my answer, which was accepted. As far as I can tell in the faqs, autoawarded bounty goes to the answer with the most votes, so that would be the other one. It just seems strange, is all. Not to worry.

Comment: @TheBloodyPoet no, if a bounty is auto-awarded, only answers posted after the bounty was started are eligible.  (The reasoning is that bounties are usually posted because the existing answers aren't good enough for whatever the bounty-poster needs.)  A bounty can be *manually* awarded to any answer.